# Anyone help me to convert this mySQL query to laravel eloquent ORM?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```sql
SELECT
    team_name,
    (CASE WHEN `assignment` = 'Appeal/Recon/Claim Review' THEN `done` ELSE 0 END) AS 'Appeal', 
    (CASE WHEN `assignment` = 'IDR' THEN `done` ELSE 0 END) AS 'IDR'
FROM
    operation_assignments  
WHERE
    serial = 6 
GROUP BY
    team_name
```

```php
$collections = DB::table('operation_assignments')
    ->select(
        'team_name', 
        DB::raw("CASE WHEN assignment = 'Appeal/Recon/Claim Review' THEN done ELSE 0 END AS Appeal"),
        DB::raw("CASE WHEN assignment = 'IDR' THEN done ELSE 0 END AS IDR")
    )
    ->where('serial', 6)
    ->groupBy('team_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I run this it gives me an error on violation group by.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this query? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$collections = OperationAssignment::select([
    'team_name',
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN assignment='Appeal/Recon/Claim Review' THEN done END) as 'appeal'"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN assignment='IDR' THEN done END) as 'idr'"),
])
->where('serial', 6)
->groupBy('team_name')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Eloquent extends the base query builder so the syntax is the same. The only difference is instead of `DB::table('operation_assignments')`, you use your model (I'm assuming it's `App\Models\OperationAssignment`).

```
# app/Models/OperationAssignment.php

namespace App\Models;

class OperationAssignment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'operation_assignments';

    ...
}
```

```php
use App\Models\OperationAssignment;

$collections = OperationAssignment::query()
    ->select(...)
    ->where(...)
    ->groupBy(...)
    ->get();
```